# How to filter one ui.select2 based on the selected value in another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have these items on my scope:

```
$scope.states = [ 
    { StateAbbr: 'CA', StateName: 'California' },  
    { StateAbbr: 'MI', StateName: 'Michigan' }  ];

$scope.counties = [  
    { CountyName: 'ALCONA', StateAbbr: 'MI'  },  
    { CountyName: 'BENZIE', StateAbbr: 'MI' },  
    { CountyName: 'CHIPPEWA', StateAbbr: 'MI' },  
    { CountyName: 'IONIA', StateAbbr: 'MI' },
    { CountyName: 'KEWEENAW', StateAbbr: 'MI' },  
    { CountyName: 'Los Angeles', StateAbbr: 'CA' },  
    { CountyName: 'MACKINAC', StateAbbr: 'MI' },  
    { CountyName: 'Orange', StateAbbr: 'CA' },  
    { CountyName: 'Riverside', StateAbbr: 'CA' },  
    { CountyName: 'San Bernardino', StateAbbr: 'CA' },  
    { CountyName: 'San Diego', StateAbbr: 'CA' },  
    { CountyName: 'SCHOOLCRAFT', StateAbbr: 'MI' },  
    { CountyName: 'Ventura', StateAbbr: 'CA' }  ];

$scope.filterDefaults = function() {
    $scope.orderFilter = {};
    $scope.orderFilter.selectedState = '';
    $scope.orderFilter.selectedCounty = '';
};
$scope.filterDefaults();
```

the markup:

```
<label>State</label>
<select data-ui-select2="select2Options" name="stateName" data-ng-model="orderFilter.selectedState" data-placeholder="Choose a state…">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option data-ng-repeat="s in states" value="{{s.StateAbbr}}">{{s.StateName}}</option>
</select>

<label>County</label>
<select data-ui-select2="select2Options" name="countyName" data-ng-model="orderFilter.selectedCounty" data-placeholder="Choose a county…" data-ng-disabled="orderFilter.selectedState == '' " >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option data-ng-repeat="c in counties | filter:orderFilter.selectedState" value="{{c.CountyName}}">{{c.CountyName}}</option>
</select>
```

How to I correctly set up the filter so that the counties are filtered by the state?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that filter:selectedState.StateAbbr was the wrong object, it should be filter:**orderFilter**.selectedState (which would be the StateAbbr)

Once that change was made then it works like a champ

Answer (score 1):

On the ng-model of the State dropdown, you can use selectedState instead of orderFilter.selectedState.

Here is how it should look.

```
<div class="span2">
    <label>State</label>
    <select data-ui-select2="select2Options" data-ng-model="selectedState" data-ng-    options="s.StateName for s in states" data-placeholder="Choose a state…">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="span2">
    <label>County</label>
    <select data-ui-select2="select2Options" data-ng-model="orderFilter.selectedCounty" data-ng-options="c.CountyName for c in counties | filter:selectedState.StateAbbr" data-placeholder="Choose a county…">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the working jsFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/vikasgoyalgzs/mNL3h/

Please make sure you click the button to update the dropdowns with data.

Hope this helps.